# Current flow based on voltage difference

Tags: batteries, current

If I have two sources of DC current, one of 28V and the other of 26V - the LOAD will preffer the higher voltage source ?

I'm trying to create a DC-UPS without any kind of "failover" switches, the AC-DC PSU is set for 28V and the SLA-AGM battery at 26V - my load will consume the battery (even a tiny bit) or it will preffer the higher voltage source (AC-DC PSU) ?

The battery current flow is controlled with diodes so in theory they will NOT be charged by the AC-DC PSU and it will only provide current if needed.

Thank you!

Comment: most loads are unable to make preferential choices. They get what they are given and do their best to obey the laws of physics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hard to give a definitive answer to this without seeing a schematic. If as you say there are diodes between the battery and the 28V supply / load (as shown below), and IF the 28V supply voltage is indeed greater than the battery voltage, the diodes will be back-biased and no current will be drawn from the battery, and you will not accidentally charge the battery.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f9y8gH.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

If the 28V droops though, perhaps due to excessive load, the battery will begin to start supplying current when the voltage falls to a level where the diodes can conduct.

That should not be an issue though. It should self balance and the load will draw split current from wherever can supply it.

**However:** If you do not already have so, I would add another diode from the supply to the load ( in position D2 of the schematic above) to ensure that when the supply droops or turns off.. you do not end up driving whatever it is from your battery.

Comment: Thank you! I won't add diodes to PSU - I'm willing to use 2x http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/260/RSP-1000-SPEC-806406.pdf (RSP-1000-27) connected in parallel as it's supported by the product for load balancing.

Comment: The diode \$D_2\$ is normally not required as this is normally part of the AC to DC full-bridge rectifier.

Comment: @skvery You are right, in many cases it will not be needed. It depends on the nature of the supply, and also if the supply is also driving some other part of the system.